# Update a json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having problems trying to sort this on my own.

I have a hidden field containing a small amount of json.

I populate a variable using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var data = $("#result").text();
var j = JSON.parse(data);
j.my_item.total_price==="2222";
console.log(j.my_item.total_price);

});
```

the variable j is showing the correct data, I just don't have a clue how to update the total_price

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to enable me to update total_price?

Comment: Did you try j.my_item.total_price="2222"; ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign to an object property just like any other variable:

```
j.my_item.total_price = "2222";
```

Or the alternative (array-like) syntax:

```
j['my_item']['total_price'] = "2222";
```

Or mix-and-match:

```
j.my_item['total_price'] = "2222";
j['my_item'].total_price = "2222";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = $("#result").text();
var j = JSON.parse(data);
j.my_item.total_price="2222";
console.log(j.my_item.total_price);

});
```

`===` isn't an assignment operator, it's a type-strict comparison operator.

See here:

[Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)